# jQuery plug-in set options inside an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Not sure if my Title is the right way to ask how to do this but... 
Here i have a plug-in called **func** which sets default options:

```
(function($){
$.fn.func= function(options){

    var settings = $.extend({
        color:'white',
        hoverColor: 'black'
    },options);

    return this.each(function(){
        if(settings.color){
            $(this).css('color',settings.color);
        }
        if(settings.hoverColor){
            $(this).css('color',settings.hoverColor);
        }
    }
```

Now here is where the user can change the color of the text to what they want:

```
$('#selector').func({
    color:'blue',
    hoverColor: 'green'
});
```

Now here is what i want to accomplish: I want to be able to break up the hover and link options to look like the following:

```
$('#selector').func({
    link:
        color: 'blue'
    ,hover:
        color: 'green'
});
```

Similar to jQuery validation plug-in [HERE](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) where they break up the rules and the message options. Let me know if you need additional information. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in what you want to accomplish is invalid so you will always get a syntax error.

Try

```
$('#selector').func({
    link: {color: 'blue'},
    hover: {color: 'green'}
});
```

Of course you will have to use the same structure in the initial `settings` object (*use the deep copy version of `$.extend`, by providing true as the first argument, since we are using objects*)

```
var settings = $.extend(true, {
        link: {color: 'white'},
        hover: {color: 'black'}
    },options);
```

and you access them with `settings.link.color` and `settings.hover.color`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this is exactly what i was looking for. I figured it was something like in your example i just couldn't think of how to write it. Thanks

Comment: what do you meen by deep copy version of `$.extend`? I am curious.

Comment: @mitch, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ The second version which takes a boolean as its first parameter will perform a deep copy(*the merging of the objects is recursive*). This is required when copying objects because the default behaviour for JS is to create references to objects. (*so `var a = {}, b=a;` then `b['key'] = 'value'` will show in both `a` and `b` since they reference the same object.*)